# Tab function in css?

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have the following code & js files are included at top of the page.

> **HTML**

```
<ul class="tabs">
 <li><a href="#tabr1">Tab1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#tabr2">Tab2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#tabr3">Tab3</a></li>
 </ul>

   <div id="tabr1" class="tab-content">Tab1</div>
 <div id="tabr2" class="tab-content">Tab2</div>
<div id="tabr3" class="tab-content">Tab3</div>
```

> **CSS**

```
 ul.tabs{
margin:10px 0 -1px 0;
 padding:0;
width:100%;
 border-bottom:1px solid #e5e5e5;
 float:left;
  }

  ul.tabs li{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0 2px 0 0;
padding:0;
display:inline-block;
*display:inline;/*IE ONLY*/
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
*top:1px;/*IE 7 ONLY*/
zoom:1;
}

ul.tabs li a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#666;
display:inline-block;
padding:9px 15px;
position: relative;
top:0;
left:0;
line-height:100%;
background:#f5f5f5;
box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
border:1px solid #e5e5e5;
border-bottom:0;
font-size:0.9em;
zoom:1;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover{
background:#fff;
}

ul.tabs li.current a{
position:relative;
top:1px;
left:0;
background:#fff;
box-shadow: none;
color:#222;
}

.tab-content{
border:1px solid #efefef;
border-left:1px solid #e5e5e5;
clear:both;
padding:20px;
margin:0 0 40px 0;
}
```

When i use this codes in my program all the tabs are assembling in the same page.  I cant able to hide other tabs when a tab is active.

What will be the reason for this

But i check this in this [site](http://www.99lime.com/elements/).

If anyone has any suggestion??

Comment: I dont use any js i will upload my css in few sec

Comment: You have to include the library you've download from that site. Try to download and puts your code to the blank.html file

Comment: You need JS for this, Vivek! Here is a simple jQuery tutorial http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-tabs

Comment: In the page you mention, there is js used to realize the tab functionality. If you want to use css only, then you have just static pages, that look like tabs, but reload the full page.

Comment: @Sven Bieder thats right i planned to finish this by css only how ever i will add js file to this thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QdhtG/)**

This help you to solve your problem in many ways.

> 

```
   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
       <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>

       <div class="content">
           <p>Stuff for Tab One</p>
       </div> 
   </div>

   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>

       <div class="content">
           <p>Stuff for Tab Two</p>

           <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100">
       </div> 
   </div>

    <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>

       <div class="content">
           <p>Stuff for Tab Three</p>

           <img src="http://placedog.com/200/100">
       </div> 
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to use js files then here is the pure CSS tab

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabs">

       <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
           <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>

           <div class="content">
               <p>Stuff for Tab One</p>
           </div> 
       </div>

       <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
           <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>

           <div class="content">
               <p>Stuff for Tab Two</p>

               <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/100">
           </div> 
       </div>

        <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
           <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>

           <div class="content">
               <p>Stuff for Tab Three</p>

               <img src="http://placedog.com/200/100">
           </div> 
       </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
.tab label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; cursor:pointer
}
.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 

  overflow: hidden;
}
.content > * {
  opacity: 0;

  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform:    translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform:     translateX(-100%);
  -o-transform:      translateX(-100%);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.6s ease;
  -ms-transition:     all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition:      all 0.6s ease;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content > * {
  opacity: 1;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform:    translateX(0);
  -ms-transform:     translateX(0);
  -o-transform:      translateX(0);
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QdhtG/)**

Comment: Thats is what i needed without using js file to achieve tab function

Comment: Thanks for the code but how did you enter html content to a fiddle. Because i tried a lot to show example but i was not able to enter text in html content  of jsfiddle

Comment: You can.. Refresh the fiddle page and try

Comment: I tried many times. In that panels tab on left side of the page  has three Selectors Html Css and Javascript. But HTML is always deactivated in this

Comment: Some one is making fun of this. First one down vote for my question Then for @Ravia answer now for you. Who ever making this is really playing with his vote

Answer (score 1):

You have added the code, but did you also add jQuery links in the header section (.js files) of HTML.

You need to add <script src="/site/templates/js/kickstart.js" type="text/javascript">
 & other js files

Comment: The down voter do bother to comment what is wrong with the answer

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I didnt think that js is necessary for this sor i excluded that file. I will add that file

Comment: Dont mention it i am the one to thank you for solving my problem

Comment: If your problem is solved please mark the answer as correct answer

Comment: @VivekDragon if your query is solved please mark the answer as correct